# Using IF,ISnumber and Find

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I am trying to use IF with ISnumber and Find but due to some error its not working in VBA and its to long also so thats why it is getting change.

Actual formula

```
  =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("CS&L",C3)),"CS&L",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EMPLX",C3)),"Employee Cross Charges",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EOCINV",C3)),"EOC Specific Recharges (Inventory Related)",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EOCNINV",C3)),"EOC Specific Recharges (Non - Inventory Related)",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("EXPAT",C3)),"Expats",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("GLBSC",C3)),"Global Service Charges",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("INFSY",C3)),"Information Systems",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("TRDDL",C3)),"International Trade Deals",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("IREXP",C3)),"Intra-Region Expats",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MGMTF",C3)),"Management Fees (Below OC)",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MANUF",C3)),"Manufacturing",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("MARKT",C3)),"Marketing",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("OVERH",C3)),"Overheads",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("PROCUR",C3)),"Procurement",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("PCTGR",C3)),"Product Category Reviews",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RD&Q",C3)),"RDQ",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("RESTR",C3)),"Restructuring / Project",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("ROYAL",C3)),"Royalties",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("STRAT",C3)),"Strategy",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("TRDMK",C3)),"Trademarks","Others"))))))))))))))))))))
```

After creating macro its getting change which is getting error

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'

'
    Range("B2").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""CS&L"",R[1]C[1])),""CS&L"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""EMPLX"",R[1]C[1])),""Employee Cross Charges"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""EOCINV"",R[1]C[1])),""EOC Specific Recharges (Inventory Related)"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""EOCNINV"",R[1]C[1])),""EOC Specific Recharges (Non - Inventory Related)"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""EXPAT"",R[1]C[1])),""Expats"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""GLBSC"",R" & _
        "),""Global Service Charges"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""INFSY"",R[1]C[1])),""Information Systems"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""TRDDL"",R[1]C[1])),""International Trade Deals"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""IREXP"",R[1]C[1])),""Intra-Region Expats"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""MGMTF"",R[1]C[1])),""Management Fees (Below OC)"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""MANUF"",R[1]C[1])),""Manufacturing"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""MAR" & _
        "C[1])),""Marketing"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""OVERH"",R[1]C[1])),""Overheads"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""PROCUR"",R[1]C[1])),""Procurement"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""PCTGR"",R[1]C[1])),""Product Category Reviews"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""RD&Q"",R[1]C[1])),""RDQ"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""RESTR"",R[1]C[1])),""Restructuring / Project"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""ROYAL"",R[1]C[1])),""Royalties"",IF(ISNUMBE" & _
        "STRAT"",R[1]C[1])),""Strategy"",IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(""TRDMK"",R[1]C[1])),""Trademarks"",""Others""))))))))))))))))))))"
    Range("B3").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Does cell `C3` hold several words or it's expected to contain only one of the words you are searching for in the formula (i.e. the whole cell will contain only one of this values "CS&L", "EMPLX", "EOCINV", "EOCNINV", "EXPAT", etc)

Comment: What's your objective to write an excel formula in `B2` or to have a VBA that writes the result `B2`?

Comment: it contains multiple words like abc_expat_ksba in C3 and in B3 we using it to find its excat nae for it can be used in other excel macros on different criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some points to note:

1. Long formulas are difficult to read, I suggest to use `[Alt]` + `[Enter]` keys combined to start a new line in the same cell thus breaking the formula in several lines *(see fig. 1)*.
2. `FIND` is case sensitive, instead use `SEARCH` *(see fig. 1)*.
3. It seems that you try record a macro to get the formula as VBA, be aware that very long formulas are not properly recorded into VBA. Nevertheless you can use the procedure below to print the entire formula of the `ActiveCell` in the Visual Basic Immediate Window.

   ```
   Sub Get_Formula()
   Rem Opens Immediate Window and Clears it
   SendKeys "^g^a{DEL}": Stop

   With ActiveCell
       Debug.Print vbLf; vbLf; String(131, "*")
       Debug.Print "Formula in Wbk\Wsh\Cell: "; .Parent.Parent.Name; " \ "; .Parent.Name; " \ "; .Address(0, 0)
       Debug.Print ActiveCell.Formula
       Debug.Print vbLf; String(131, "*"); vbLf
   End With
   SendKeys "^g^{HOME}" ': Stop
   End Sub
   ```

As regards the formula, there are several solutions, I will list three of them.

*These formulas assume the list of strings to associate with the corresponding description is located in `B7:B28`*

1. **Standard Excel Formula**: Using a standard long formula like the one you posted, just replace FIND with SEARCH as the target word could be in lower or upper case *(see Fig 1)*. The issue with long formulas is that they are difficult to read and required heavy maintenance. Enter this formula in `C7` and copy till last record *(see Fig. 1)*.

   ```
   =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("CS&L",$B7)),"CS&L",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EMPLX",$B7)),"Employee Cross Charges",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EOCINV",$B7)),"EOC Specific Recharges (Inventory Related)",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EOCNINV",$B7)),"EOC Specific Recharges (Non - Inventory Related)",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("EXPAT",$B7)),"Expats",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("GLBSC",$B7)),"Global Service Charges",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("INFSY",$B7)),"Information Systems",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TRDDL",$B7)),"International Trade Deals",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("IREXP",$B7)),"Intra-Region Expats",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MGMTF",$B7)),"Management Fees (Below OC)",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MANUF",$B7)),"Manufacturing",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("MARKT",$B7)),"Marketing",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("OVERH",$B7)),"Overheads",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PROCUR",$B7)),"Procurement",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("PCTGR",$B7)),"Product Category Reviews",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RD&Q",$B7)),"RDQ",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("RESTR",$B7)),"Restructuring / Project",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("ROYAL",$B7)),"Royalties",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("STRAT",$B7)),"Strategy",
   IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("TRDMK",$B7)),"Trademarks","Others"))))))))))))))))))))
   ```

   [image]

*Fig. 1*

2. **FormulaArray**: For data like the one you are using the best practice is to create a table to hold the relationship  between the different elements *(i.e Short Description to Description in this case)* as mentioned by *user1016274*. However, I would specifically suggest to create an `Excel Table` *(*`ListObject` *in VBA)* due to the advantage of using its structured references in formulas and VBA *(see [Use structured references in Excel table formulas](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Use-structured-references-in-Excel-table-formulas-75FB07D3-826A-449C-B76F-363057E3D16F))*

   In this case I created an `Excel Table` in a separated worksheet, so it does not cause any disruption to the rest of the reports and data you might have in the workbook. The `Excel Table` is named `tDescriptions` *(see fig. 2a)*.

   [image]

   *Fig. 2a*

   Then we use a `FormulaArray` to retrieve the associated Description from the table. Enter this `FormulaArray` in `D7` and copy till last record *(see Fig 2b)*.

   ```
   =IF(SUM(1*NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(tDescriptions[Short.Desc],ShortLongDesc!$B7))))=0,"Others",
   INDEX(tDescriptions[Description],
   SUM((1*NOT(ISERR(SEARCH(tDescriptions[Short.Desc],ShortLongDesc!$B7))))
   *(ROW(tDescriptions)-ROW(tDescriptions[#Headers])))))
   ```

   [image]

   *Fig. 2b*
3. **User Defined Function (UDF)**: Although we can use an Array to hold the Short Description to Description relationship, I prefer to keep it in the `Excel Table` created in the previous point as it's easier to maintain. Enter this formula in `E7`. *(see Fig 3)*

   ```
   =Get_LongDescription(B7)
   ```

   [image]

   *Fig. 3*

   Below is the code of the UDF. The argument entered can be a string or one cell reference, if entered a range with more than one cell the UDF will return an error.

   ```
   Option Explicit

   Public Function Get_LongDescription(sText As String) As String
   Dim Lob As ListObject
   Dim lRow As Long
       Rem Set Default Result
       Get_LongDescription = "Others"
       Rem Set Objects
       Set Lob = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ShortLongDesc(Tbl)").ListObjects("tDescriptions")
       Rem Search SHort Desc in Text
       With Lob
           For lRow = 1 To .DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
               If InStr(LCase(sText), LCase(.ListColumns("Short.Desc").DataBodyRange.Cells(lRow).Value2)) <> 0 Then
                   Get_LongDescription = .ListColumns("Description").DataBodyRange.Cells(lRow).Value2
                   Exit For
       End If: Next: End With
       End Function
   ```

Comment: ok i got this... but which one of this is easy to use and edit. Also which one can find accurate data without being case sensitive

Comment: Options 2 & 3 are easier to maintain, both are no-case sensitive and require to create and update the Excel Table. Between this two I prefer option 3, It only depends on your choice to use VBA or not.

Comment: i am ok with option 3 but how to implement i am little bit confuse i tried that.

Comment: 1. Have you used Excel tables before? 2. Do you know how to use an UDF (user defined function)?   Please let me know what problems have you encountered at implementing it so I can help you with it.

Comment: I used tables before but not UDF and i tried to implement and i got confused in what should be short.desc in formula and etc.

Comment: Follow this 3 steps to implement Option 3: First step is to create in a new worksheet the Excel table  as described in point 2. Formula Array, named the excel table as `tDescription` the resulting table should looks as in Fig. 2a (visit the suggest page Use structured references in Excel table formulas). Second step is to add a new VBA module and copy the UDF Function Get_LongDescription(sText As String) As String. Third step is to replace your actual formula with this `=Get_LongDescription(B7)`. Do let me know of any question you may.

Comment: ok, i tried that thing it works but what i need is to use this formula on column B and table will be on another sheet. Also it is showing only Others nothing else for me. Can you attach any excel with all 3 Examples...Thanks in advance.

Comment: The formula can be used in any cell? What stops you from placing the formula in column `B`?

Comment: I might be done some thing wrong then i tried this. Also what is ShortLongDesc(Tbl) might be i done this wrong.

=Get_LongDescription(C3)

Comment: What option have are you trying?

Comment: Its worked my mistake in code my table and sheet not matching.

Comment: It's working or not? have you identify the mistake? it's Ok now.. don't understand what do you mean?

Comment: its working now. Due to some mistake by me in Coding its not finding sheet with name ShortLongDesc(Tbl) as my sheet name is Sheet1 and table name is also different thats why its not working.

Comment: 1 more question how to make it non case sensitive as right now its case sensitive.

Comment: Option 3 is non case sensitive.. This line makes both ( `sText` and the `Table Item` ) lower case before comparison: `InStr(LCase(sText), LCase(.ListColumns("Short.Desc").DataBodyRange.Cells(lRow).Value2))`

Comment: but it is taking only upper case

Comment: I have attached link above please see.

Comment: Got your file, somehow I cannot open it, however I was able to extract the data (no macros). Now please tell me where you are having an unexpected behavior of the UDF and what is your expected result (i.e. row `3` formula is returning "Others" and I expect "Marketing" because column `C` contains "Marketing") then I'll be able to check and correct if there is any error or explain to you what's wrong with your expectation and what you should do... but as of now I have nothing to work with, the UDF is non-case sensitive. To validate this replace in `C16` `RTM` with `rtm` you'll same result

Comment: you can download file its showing macro also with help of ALT+F12 and you are correct its showing others in many cells. RTM is added by me  But its should get atleast rest correct.

Comment: Please nee details, the formulas is working as expected, so tell me in which cells it's returning wrong values (i.e. row 3 formula is returning "Others" and I expect "Marketing" because column C contains "Marketing") then I'll be able to check and correct if there is any error or explain to you what's wrong with your expectation and what you should do

Comment: from B3 to B10 it should be marketing and B51 it should be employee cross charges. Like this its not picking up all values leaving Expat...

Comment: May I ask you to review and tell me why `B3:B10` should be Marketing? As regards `B51`, `Employee Cross Charges` is not even in your table, are expecting a sort magic here?

Comment: Sorry my mistake i have saved the new table but i think wrong table is uploaded. I check and let you know again and i understood for marketing i  have to use 3 aberrations then only it will work... Sorry for disturbing you....

Answer (score 1):

You can well keep using a worksheet function for this. The formula just translates tokens/abbreviations into longer terms, or "other" if unknown. I would separate the translation formula from the data like this:
1) create a 2-column table somewhere on that sheet, with column 1 holding tokens and column 2 the corresponding term:

```
CS&L    CS&L
EMPLX   Employee Cross Charges
EOCINV  EOC Specifiic Recharges (Inventory Related)
```

For ease of use, give that range (say, X1:Y3) a name like "terms".
2) Then, in your table, use a formula which looks up a short token and returns the longer term - `VLOOKUP()`:

```
=IF(ISNV(VLOOKUP(C3,terms,2,FALSE)),"other",VLOOKUP(C3,terms,2,FALSE))
```

It looks a bit convoluted because it needs to evaluate the lookup twice to check for an unknown token. But, in contrast to your first formula, there is no data included in the formula itself. Neither is the size of the translation table restricted.

**addendum:**
If the short terms are not the only text in the cell then the above formula will return an error all the time; it only compares the whole cell's contents (`C3`). I think that's what you mention in the comment.

In order to mimick `FIND` completely use this:

```
={INDEX(longterms,MAX(MAX(IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(shortterms,C3)),0,1)*ROW(shortterms)),MIN(ROW(shortterms)))-ROW(longterms)+1)}
```

Enter this as a matrix formula (enter with Ctrl-Shift-Enter).
Here, I use `SEARCH` to find text without looking at the case - you can use `FIND` instead if you want to take the case into account.
The innermost `SEARCH` creates an array of row numbers (if term is found) or 0 (if not found) of the `shortterm` named range.
`MAX`creates a single value from that array.
This row number is taken as an `INDEX` into the named range `longterms` which is adjacent to `shortterms`.
The `MIN` function is only needed to change the value 0 (if a term is not found) into the row number of the first entry of `longterms` - which needs to be the "other" text. 
So the 2 named ranges look like:

```
U7: (empty) V7: other
U8: EMPLX   V8: Employee Cross Charges
U9: EOCINV  V9: EOC Specifiic Recharges (Inventory Related)
```

Define `shortterms` as $U$7:$U$9 and `longterms` as $V$7:$V$9 .

Comment: For 2007 and later you can simplify to: `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,terms,2,FALSE),"other")`

Comment: for me both If(INSV and IFerror showing other only in all cells,

=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C3,U1:V23,2,FALSE),"other")
=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C3,U:V,1,0)),"other",VLOOKUP(C3,U:V,1,0))

Comment: @user1016274 I tried your method it work but what i is searching is like ABAC_EMPLX_emplx ,etc so t will not work exactly for every thing

Comment: @vicky: I tested the formula again and it works even if the keyword is embedded in other text. 2 things MUST be observed: 1. it's a matrix formula, enter it with Ctrl-Shift-Return, 2. the "shortterms" and "longterms" columns MUST not be whole columns - for 20 terms, define for example shortterms as U2:U21, longterms as V2:V21. NO blank cells at the end!

Comment: Ok . I will test again and let you know